# Is it possible to install Sitecore in local for free?

Tags: sitecore-client, solr, sitecore-commerce

Is it possible to install in local for free just for learning purpose? . please help me with it.

Comment: No, it is not possible. You need to find a parter company that works with Sitecore to get the developer license.

Comment: Thank you @Anton